# Unusual "value cannot be null"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an unusual problem on the server where I host my website (on local works just fine).

In a post request, I pass some values to a list, in case I get an error message from the model not being valid, so the data can remain on the screen while the user make the changes (the data I'm referring to is in a table, on the same page with the form)

```
@if (Model.IncomeExpensesViewModel.LastSixIncomeExpenses.Count() > 0)
{
 for (var i = 0; i < Model.IncomeExpensesViewModel.LastSixIncomeExpenses.Count(); i++)
 {
 @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.IncomeExpensesViewModel.LastSixIncomeExpenses[i].Sum, new { @Value = Model.IncomeExpensesViewModel.LastSixIncomeExpenses[i].Sum })
 @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.IncomeExpensesViewModel.LastSixIncomeExpenses[i].Tag, new { @Value = Model.IncomeExpensesViewModel.LastSixIncomeExpenses[i].Tag })
 @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.IncomeExpensesViewModel.LastSixIncomeExpenses[i].Date, new { @Value = Model.IncomeExpensesViewModel.LastSixIncomeExpenses[i].Date })
 @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.IncomeExpensesViewModel.LastSixIncomeExpenses[i].Type, new { @Value = Model.IncomeExpensesViewModel.LastSixIncomeExpenses[i].Type })
  }
}
```

So when I submit the input info, I get the error

```
Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source
```

on this line

```
@if (Model.IncomeExpensesViewModel.LastSixIncomeExpenses.Count() > 0)
```

`Model.IncomeExpensesViewModel.LastSixIncomeExpenses` is a `List<SingleIncomeExpenseViewModel>`

I tried with Count() and Any(). It didn't work.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Have you tried `.Count` without the parenthesis?

Comment: @EBrown `Count()` is a method in IEnumerables.

Comment: Are you certain that `Model.IncomeExpensesViewModel.LastSixIncomeExpenses` is not null?  That's what the exception indicates.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway well it is null, and in that case I don't send any hidden data. But why does it crash at the IF statement

Comment: Because that's where you're trying to get the `Count` of a `null` object.  You will need to make sure it's not `null` first, and then check the count.

Comment: @PoweredByOrange https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27b47ht3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx The `List<T>` type contains an explicit `.Count` property. (Though that doesn't seem to be the issue here, seems to be a `NullReferenceException`.)

Comment: Based on the error message; none of your objects are null or you would get a NullReference error message. Count() is a method and doesn't take any parameters; so that can't be the problem either.

Your question refers to "when I submit" ... which tells me this error is generated during the postback.  The error message corroborates that also.

My first suspicion is that the error is not being generated at the source location that you believe.

Comment: @MarcJohnston - not exactly, referring to https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/bb337697%28v=vs.110%29.aspx - `Any()` and `Count()` throws ArgumentNullException when source is null, not NullReferenceException. What is more, `Count()` do take parameters but there is also a no-parameter overload.

Comment: @MarcJohnston, so I've started to dig deeper. I've inserted manually a row in the table where I wanted to insert with the form, and the date is changes, it's in a different format from the one on my local machine. Could this be a problem? P.S. I tried adding the != null stuff and I don't get the error anymore but I don't do any inserts aswell.

Comment: try this .. foreach (var incomeModel in  Model.IncomeExpensesViewModel.LastSixIncomeExpenses ??  new Model.IncomeExpensesViewModel.LastSixIncomeExpenses ())

Comment: @Adam, thank you for the suggestion, but I think I found the issue. So when I insert a row in the DB, besides all of the data, I also insert a date. I get this date from a field where I use a JS Datepicker. I changed the format of the date to `dd.mm.yyyy` and because of the culture, when I insertsome data in the DB I get `mm.dd.yyyy`. So if I wanted to insert something in 20th May (20.05.2015 in my timezone), I was inserting 5th of X (i'm getting the date as a string from the field and convert it before I call the SP). I'll fix this tomorrow. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Why on earth are you using `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.IncomeExpensesViewModel.LastSixIncomeExpenses[i].Sum, new { @Value = Model.IncomeExpensesViewModel.LastSixIncomeExpenses[i].Sum })` - it should be just `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.IncomeExpensesViewModel.LastSixIncomeExpenses[i].Sum)` - you don't need to override the `value` attribute to set it to exactly was it already is

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your statement to `@if (Model.IncomeExpensesViewModel.LastSixIncomeExpenses != null && Model.IncomeExpensesViewModel.LastSixIncomeExpenses.Count() > 0)` cause you cannot enumerate null collection.

The same is with `.Any()` - it doesn't check whether collection is not null so it throws exception in that case.